# Regular expression matchig hh:mm time but no "00:00"

Tags: regex, time

Can anybody help me with expression matching  HH:MM but NOT 00:00   ??

I'm trying to use it to catch some task duration time, so, "00:00" is not valid time, but I can't find any similar exp.

thanks a lot

Comment: Why is 00:00 invalid? Surely a task could take less than half a second.

Comment: i think `99:99` is not  a valid time.

Answer (score 1):

24 hour format.

```
^(?!00:00$)(?:[10]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!00:00$)\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/2

Comment: @EmreAcar OP has not asked for it.Can you please read the question again.neither has he specified it would `12` or `24` hr clock

Comment: Whatever, let OP decide.

Comment: How will hours increase if minutes dont have a range, i just can't get this. Only way this answer is going valid is OP trusts it's source of task times.